# Higher derivatives of the log-partition function

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-mechanics

I need higher derivatives of the log-partition function $Z(z)=\log \sum_i \exp(z_i)$, has anyone derived the formula?

Looking at [concrete values](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/symmetric-softmax-decomposition.nb) of derivatives up to order 8, evaluated at $z=(1,1,1)$ makes me suspect there's a nice formula in terms of $p_i=\frac{\exp z_i}{Z}$

$$H_2=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{2}{9} & -\frac{1}{9} & -\frac{1}{9} \\
 -\frac{1}{9} & \frac{2}{9} & -\frac{1}{9} \\
 -\frac{1}{9} & -\frac{1}{9} & \frac{2}{9} \\
\end{array}
\right)=\text{diag}(p)-pp'
$$

$$H_3=\left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
 -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} \\
 -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} \\
 -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
 \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
 \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
 -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} \\
\end{array}\right)
\right]$$

([crossposted](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/688908/higher-derivatives-of-the-log-partition-function) on physics.SE)